# redirect to another view function

Tags: django

As users login I'd like to redirect them simply to index instead of having '/login/' in the url.

I have two view functions one for login and index.

index view

```
def index(request):

    context = {

    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

login view

```
def login(request):

    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
    else:
        print('Wrong user') 

    return redirect('index') #<------ Something like that(?)
```

url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

            url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),      
]
```

Console error:

```
Correct user
Internal Server Error: /Crowd/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 66, in login
    return redirect('index')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 116, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 204, in resolve_url
    return urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 600, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
[14/Sep/2016 19:46:12] "POST /Crowd/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 88875
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# views.py
def login(...):
    # ...
    return redirect('home')
```

and:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'views.index', name='home'),
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get an error while trying to do the above. I've updated my post with it.

Comment: It really should work, make sure all files are saved to the correct location (by injecting an error with `1/0` and verifying that it happens) and restart, then try again